# 'On the computer' vs 'At the computer'

Tags: prepositions

Are they all grammatically correct  and do they all have the same meaning ?

> 1. She was **on the computer** writing an email a minute or two ago.
> 2. She was **at the computer** writing an email a minute or two ago.
> 3. She was  writing an email **on the computer** a minute or two ago.
> 4. She was  writing an email **at the computer** a minute or two ago.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Literally speaking:

Cat on the computer:
[image: cat lying on a keyboard]

Cat at the computer:
[image: cat with its paws on the keyboard of a laptop]

However, someone might be said to be "at the computer" just meaning that they are physically at the computer station without necessarily using it:

[image: cat sleeping in front of a computer with its head on a mouse]

And they might be said to be "on the computer" meaning that their attention/activity is on using the computer:

[image: Cat looking at something on a computer monitor]

Answer (score 14):

Generally, for all intents and purposes, they mean the same thing and all four of your examples are fine.

They do have a slightly different meaning, though.

> on the computer

This specifically means that the person was using the computer.  There's no question about whether the person was actually writing the email in a program on the computer.

> at the computer

This implies that someone is immediately in front of the computer but does not necessarily require that someone is using the computer.

Writing emails pretty much requires the use of a computer, so in this case, the meanings are identical but, if I change the action slightly:

> She was *on the computer* taking notes for class.

This pretty much means that she was taking notes using her computer.

> She was *at the computer* taking notes for class.

This **could** (but does not necessarily) mean that she was using the computer to take notes but it could **also** mean that she was using the computer to get the information for her notes but was actually writing them down on a piece of paper or in a notebook.

Comment: Thanks.  " 'I am going to be at the computer soon so we can chat online ' told my friend." ..but we should not use "on the computer" in this structure?

Comment: I'm going to **be** at/on the computer soon so we can chat online. Both are fine.

Comment: To clarify the answer (+1) because @Murat asked: You can be **on** the computer and **on** the phone and **on** the internet, describing different ways to connect. You can be **at** the computer, **at** the bus stop and **at** the table, describing a place. If you use the computer to chat, you use *and* sit in front at the same time and therefore you can use on and at interchangeably *for this example*.