# sitting "by" the computer Vs. sitting "next to" the computer?

Tags: prepositions

The guy who's sitting here in the picture, he is sitting **by** the computer or sitting **next to** the computer?

I need this preposition, because sometimes people call me and ask me "what are you doing" and I want to say that I'm sitting or dealing with the computer, but I would like to know what a native English speaker would say in such case.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52122/on-the-computer-vs-at-the-computer

Comment: @mplungjan That question doesn't mention "by" or "next to", so I don't see how it could be a duplicate.

Comment: It mentions what native speakers would say when actively using a computer - so it is answering the actual question regardless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be **I'm sitting in front of the computer** or **I'm sitting at a computer**. "A" or "the" would of course be used depending on whether it's a very specific computer or just one you happen to be working on.

This is because as others mention, "by" or "next" implies a non-participation or at best a proximity to the computer. For example, "I'm having a coffee by the computer" or "I'm sitting by a computer" would tell someone that you're near a computer but they won't know if you're using it or not.

- See here also: [How to sit at a computer](https://www.wikihow.com/Sit-at-a-Computer).

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you use **by** or **next to** then they would both give the impression that you are sitting close to your computer. However, **next to** is more specific.

The preposition **next to** means **to the side of** and the use of **by** can mean near to something or somebody.

E.g. I sit **next to** my friend in the classroom.

= the speaker is beside her best friend,

E.g. I am sitting **next to** my computer.

= I am sitting to the side of my computer.

.E.g. His desk is **by** mine.

= His desk is close to the speaker's desk  and not necessarily to the side of it.

E.g. I am sitting by my computer.

= I am close to my computer, but not necessarily to the side of it.

People also say **at their computer** which is usually taken to mean you are sitting or standing facing your computer and probably working at it as your picture shows.

Comment: I would say that in the particular use of "by/next to a computer" neither one specifically implies use of the computer whereas "at the computer" tends to